# Despite uninstalling NumPy, importing NumPy does not produce a ModuleNotFoundError. Why?

Tags: python, numpy, package

I completely uninstalled the NumPy package from my computer. Afterward, I attempted several NumPy functions, and as expected, they all produced errors.

Interestingly, though, the import statement doesn't produce an error.

How come I do not get "ModuleNotFoundError" when I attempt to import NumPy in this situation?

Comment: It's very difficult for someone to answer this without taking a look at your computer and installation setup. So it's not really an appropriate question to ask here.  Because it's not reproducible. But do you have any folder/file named numpy in your working directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the paths, appears homebrew doesn't fully uninstall NumPy. It leaves a few remnant folders named "numpy", which appears to be causing this.